# Why is "romaji" so frequently spelt as "romanji"?

Tags: orthography

Why is the word "romaji" so frequently (mis-)spelt by a fairly large number of people (including past-self) as "romanji"?

I tried searching for "misspelt "romanji"", but mainly got hits about things written in romaji being misspelt, not about the word "romaji" being misspelt.

Answer (score 5):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Japanese)

> The romanization of Japanese is the application of the Latin script to
>   write the Japanese language. This method of writing is sometimes referred to in English as rōmaji

If you know this (I didn't), your mind will automatically think **roman**ji instead of **roma**ji

You have taught me a new word and how to misspell it in less than one minute flat!

Comment: Absolutely so!!

Comment: They actually mention that the term is misspelled, but they don't say why. We're used to hearing and writing about the roman alphabet, we naturally assume the "roma" ends in "n"

Comment: Maybe some people are also drawn to the "-anji" ending because of familiarity with *Jumanji*. After all, what other common words ends in "-ji"?

Comment: @Silenus My basenji puppy and I walked up Mt. Fuji; later I studied kanji symbols in a quaint inn with lovely shoji screens.  (Never heard of Jumnaji until your comment.)

Comment: @DyingIsFun Jumanji? I think the people dealing with romaji are also dealing with Kanji (the complex japanese characters coming from chinese), so "romanji" would sound logical.

Answer (score 3):

The way the Japanese people write a foreign word or a loan word is unique and it is done using [Katakana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana).

The capital city of Italy, Rome, is "ローマ" and you pronounce it as **Ro Ma** with a long *o* sound.

The word *ji* in ローマ**字** means a character. So, the word ローマ字 (Romaji) means the **characters of Rome or Roman characters**. That's why it is written that way.

The primary reason Romaji is misspelled as Romanji could be the adjectival form of Rome in Enlish is **Roman**, not **Ro Ma** and it could cause confusion.

[Wiktionary]

Comment: I'd add the contextual closeness to Kanji which also ends in -anji.

Answer (score 0):

The answer could come from the Roman + 字 (Character/Letter)
However, one fact many non locals overlook is the eloquence of voicing an n before certain “j” and “g” phonemes.
None the less, in romaji, it is spelled as I just did, even with a small r.